# Select record from table while updating records in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have trigger which is continuously updating records in my SQL Server 2014 table.
At the same time I am selecting records from that table. The select query query takes very long time even though table contains only 50 records.

Please suggest something which will give me faster result.

Comment: Actually I guess My update process is locking the table...
Update is happening through a trigger in every 10 seconds on almost every row..



And I am showing all the rows from that table at a time in my asp.net page which is very slow... and I want it more faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some of table hints to get data without locking table.
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.120%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

```
SELECT field FROM table (nolock)
```

Comment: Please consider add more detail and an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Try to use some of table hints to get data without locking table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: I meant **in** the answer and preferably not with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not simple to answer to the question without exact details, here's few things you could consider:

Are you always reading all the rows from the table or is there a where clause that could be indexed and would that reduce locking?

Are you updating all the rows in the table, or could the update use also an index?

Is the update process that the trigger does involved in a bigger transaction? Can this update be moved in the end of the transaction, separated somehow from the long lasting operation etc. so that the table locks would be faster?

Have you looked at locking, what page is actually being locked and what is the process doing at that time or is it several different processes doing a bigger chain of blocking? Is it row level locking or is the whole table locked?

I would only use the (nolock) hint suggested by the other answers as the very last resort when you're absolutely sure that you understand what it means. It is not just something that makes things work faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`Select Name,--Fields-- from table_name with (NOLOCK)`

Comment: Please consider add more detail and an explanation to your answer.

Comment: This is enough to understand the basic query.

Comment: So, you tell me that everyone knows what a `NOLOCK` is?